# Postgresql perl : "NOTICE: elseif should be elsif at line ..."

Tags: postgresql, perl, syntax

It's not the first time I get this strange NOTICE when adding perl functions in Postgresql :

`NOTICE:  elseif should be elsif at line 11.`

This happens at CREATE FUNCTION as well as when using the function.
Of course I tried to change with elsif but then it fails with syntax error.

Any advice would be appreciated (even if I can cope with that NOTICE)

This is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hds_updatewebservers_products(character varying) 
   RETURNS boolean 
AS 
$_$ 
   my $product_ref = @_[0]; 
   # Launch update 
   $checkexitcode = system ("sudo -u dbliveud /home/dbliveud/scripts/maj/launch-all.sh " . $product_ref . " "); 
   if ($checkexitcode > 0) { 
     # Error while updating 
     return false; 
   } elseif { 
     # Ok update done 
     return true; 
   } 
$_$ 
LANGUAGE plperlu STRICT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, it works fine on my PostgreSQL 9.5 on Linux. What version and platform are you running?

Note that your function can be exploited really badly, e.g.

```
select hds_updatewebservers_products('1; rm -rf /')
```

Why are you using `elseif`? Why not just `else`? [See perl's documentation on `elseif`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/elseif.html)

Finally, you can simply (and elegantly):

```
CREATE FUNCTION hds_updatewebservers_products(character varying) RETURNS boolean AS $_$
  my $product_ref = @_[0]; # Launch update

  $product_ref =~ /^\w$/ or die 'Invalid product ref!'; # added for safety

  $checkexitcode = system ("sudo -u dbliveud /home/dbliveud/scripts/maj/launch-all.sh " . $product_ref . " ");

  # positive value means error while updating, otherwise update done OK
  return !($checkexitcode > 0);
$_$ LANGUAGE plperlu STRICT;
```

Comment: Firstly, yes you're right : why am I using elseif instead of else ? Good question. That's the first problem/error to be corrected.

Comment: Secondly, about security, it's a 100% internal function that is used based on internal data, imported from another internal database, therefore no risk. But I also like to secure everything ("better be safe than sorry") and I will secure my perl function based on your advice : a great thank you for your help !

Comment: P. S. The Postgresql version is 8.3.17 with perl 5.10.0 (yes I know a little old but it works well. Linux stability means sometimes older versions in production)